# Saving PPT keeping voice recording

Tags: ms-office, powerpoint

I've got a PowerPoint file saved as PPTX, that needs to be a PPT, but with the voice recording still kept, ideally split per slide.

When I try to save as ppt, all voice recordings are removed. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add .ZIP to the end of the file name, you'll be able to open it as you would any other ZIP file.  Browse down to the media folder in the zip and you'll find your sound files.

Once having saved the PPTX as PPT, you can re-insert the files (if you want to embed them, you'll need to convert them to WAV, which'll also let you insert them as transition sounds, probably the simplest way to hook each sound to the matching slide)